# Can't find file path of image in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image

None of the images I have saved locally can be found when trying to import them in my project.

```
import {portfolio} from './portfolio.png'
```

Leads to "Cannot find module './portfolio.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)".

The image file path is 100% correct.

Update: Image loads however I would like to know how to remove the typescript error.

Answer (score 1):

Try default import: `import portfolio from './portfolio.png'`.

Comment: no this doesn't work either. It can't find the image file at all. Not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ES6 standard to import images into react.

If in public use the absolute path.

If it is in src you can use relative path.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

```
import MyImage from './logo.svg'; # In local
import MyImage from 'images/logo.svg'; # In Public

export default function App() {
   return(
     <div>
       <img src={MyImage} alt="logo" />
     </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: I'm using es6 method I think its a typescript error

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Joe there are multiple ways to call images-
first-

```
import image from './porfolio.png'
```

second, in this method you need to post image inside public images folder-

```
<img src="/images/image.png"/>
```

Hope these methods help you to solve your query, if you still facing issue just lemme know, I will hlep you.
Thanks

Comment: The image renders but I'm getting an annoying ts error.

Comment: What kind of error? Can you please share screenshot by link

Comment: "Cannot find module './portfolio.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"

Comment: Did you really have portfolio.png in the system folder? Also check the name of the file

Comment: Yes it's all correct because it works when I use require(). There's just a type error when I import.

Comment: If my solution helps to solve any problem then please accept my answer as solution thanks..✌️

Comment: It doesn't... I'm trying to get rid of the typescript error.